# Output filename weirdly

Tags: powershell, csv

I've written a script to extract a list of all AD groups name, that then feeds it into the next section which exports a number of CSV files based on the name of the group:

```
import-module active directory

New-Item -Path "c:\" -Name "ADlist" -ItemType "directory"

get-adgroup -filter * | sort name | select Name | export-csv -Path c:\ADlist\adlist.csv


$ADlist = Import-Csv -Path "c:\ADlist\adlist.csv"       
foreach ($ADgroup in $ADlist)
    { 

       $export = get-ADGroupMember -identity $ADgroup.name | select name |Export-Csv "$ADgroup.csv" -notypeinformation

    }
```

this works, however, the csv names are outputting weirdly and looks similar to:

> @{Name=$ADgroup}

instead of simply

> $ADgroup

is there a way to correct this to output as such?

Comment: Your last `Export-Csv "$ADgroup.csv"` is stringifying your `$ADGroup` object. You should change that to `Export-Csv "$($ADgroup.Name).csv"`

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thank you for this, this was exactly the issue, you should submit it as an answer for me to Mark accepted the answer, thanks again

Comment: I have submitted an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last `Export-Csv "$ADgroup.csv"` is stringifying your `$ADGroup` object. Since that object has a property called `Name` and an associated value, you are seeing the result in that format. You should change that to the following:

```
$export = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADgroup.name |
    Select-Object Name |
        Export-Csv "$($ADgroup.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

You can see this behavior by just surrounding a custom object in quotes or using `Write-Host`.

```
"$ADgroup"
Write-Host $ADgroup
```